# How to position node's content distant by some pixels value in cytoscape.js

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

I have set 'text-valign' property to 'bottom' for positioning node's content below that node in graph created with cytoscape.js and it is working correctly, but i want to place node's content some pixels value away (e.g.,5 px) from its current bottom position. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no way other than customizing your `cytoscape.js` file.

I tested here succesfully replacing the following line (in my 2.02 version is the line #11725):

`textY = node._private.position.y + nodeHeight / 2;`

with:

`textY = node._private.position.y + nodeHeight / 2 + 5;`

for rendering the text 5px below where it would render only with `text-valign: bottom` css property.